# Is Wang Yi more hawkish than Qin Gang?

Tags: china

> On 25 July 2023, Qin was removed from the office of Minister of
> Foreign Affairs by a decree signed by president Xi Jinping, after a
> list of appointments and removals was passed by the 14th National
> People's Congress Standing Committee.[27][28] Qin's predecessor and
> the former foreign minister of China, Wang Yi, was re-appointed to the
> office.[29] China's foreign ministry and official media agencies,
> including Xinhua News Agency, refused to explain Qin's
> dismissal.[30][31][32] All mentions of Qin during his tenure as
> foreign minister were removed from the Ministry of Foreign Affairs
> website,[33][34] though they were restored the following day.[35] With
> a tenure of 207 days, Qin is the shortest-serving foreign minister in
> the history of the People's Republic of China.[36]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_Gang

There was speculation that Qin Gang was removed in favor of Wang Yi, because Wang Yi was a lot more hawkish than Qin Gang and Xi wanted a more hawkish foreign policy. Is it true that Wang Yi is even more hawkish than Qin Gang? I couldn't really find any authoritative source demonstrating that Wang Yi is indeed more hawkish than Qin Gang who was very hawkish.

Comment: The [BBC article](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-china-66302235) covers the UK view of the affair "For some in the Party, maybe this type of person wasn't "wolf warrior" enough."  I don't know if you can call the BBC "authoritative" - it has no special access to the Chinese communist party, and is highly censored in China.

Comment: @JamesK The long British relationship between China and the U.K. in Hong Kong provided the BBC with a legacy of far more local contacts and informants in China than any other non-Chinese news agency.